# Linq to SQL order by with Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

My Environment:  ASP.net and C# in VS 2013 Express.

I have been through many similar SO articles trying to work this out.  I am amateur with Linq to SQL queries and c# in general.

I'm trying to use Linq to SQL to get the top 5 most recent distinct values from a column, then add them to a list.  My application is asp.net using c# and a .dbml file for data abstraction.

I've tried it many different ways.  I either get non-distinct yet sorted list, or I get a distinct unsorted list.  What I have so far is below

```
var Top5MFG = (from mfg in db.orders 
           where mfg.manufacturer.Length > 0 && mfg.customerid == "blahblahblahblahblah"<br />
           select new { 
              manufacturer = mfg.manufacturer,
              date = mfg.date_created 
                       })
        .Distinct()
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.date);
```

I'm thinking my "Distinct" is looking at the "ID" column, and perhaps I need to tell it I want it to look at the "manufacturer" column, but I haven't worked out how / if it's possible to do that.

I could do this with ease by using a storedproc, but I'm really trying to do it with c# code directly if possible.  This is my first post to SO, I hope I have put it together properly.  Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Several possible solutions explained in the following article : [CodeProject : DistinctBy in Linq (Find Distinct object by Property)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535374/DistinctBy-in-Linq-Find-Distinct-object-by-Propert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the GroupBy to do what you want.

```
  var Top5MFG = db.orders
     .Where (x => x.manufacturer.Length > 0 && x.customerid == "blahblahblahblahblah")
     .GroupBy(mfg => mfg.manufacturer)
     .Select(g => g.First())
     .OrderByDescending(d => d.date_created );
     .Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gets me pretty close, except, I'm only getting a single result, whereas I'd like 5 results.  Could it be due to the (g => g.First())?

Comment: @Silmar Try using `FirstOrDefault ()` instead of `First()`.

Comment: Or just `.Select(g)` and see what happens, otherwise you may have to check your data source to verify whether it actually contains data for 5 manufacturers.

Comment: Same Result I'm afraid.  I note that your original suggestion works great if I run it in LinqPad against my DB.  I wonder if my environment has something do to with it.  Updated my initial question to call out that I'm working in ASP.net and C# in VS 2013 Express.

Comment: Tried just (g) and i'm getting:  "error CS0103: The name 'g' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: If it works in LinqPad against the DB, then check your `db.orders` properties to make sure it returns adequate manufacturer data.

Comment: There was indeed an uexpected problem with my data.  This solution works, thanks everyone for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

No the `Distinct` compares `manufacturer` and `date` pairs.If you want to get distinct records by `manufacturer` then I recommend `DistinctBy` method.It's in the [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library.Since its a third library method it's not supported in linq to sql, you still can use it by fetching the records from DB and do the rest in memory

```
(from mfg in db.orders 
where mfg.manufacturer.Length > 0 && mfg.customerid == "blahblahblahblahblah"
select new { 
             manufacturer = mfg.manufacturer,
             date = mfg.date_created 
           })
 .AsEnumerable()
 .DistinctBy(x => x.manufacturer)
 .OrderByDescending(s => s.date)
 .Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm getting "Systems.Collections.... does not contain a definition for 'DistinctBy' ..."  Intellisense isn't offering it up as an option either.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can distinct by a certain field is to replace:

```
...
.Distinct()
...
```

with:

```
...
.GroupBy(x => x.manufacturer )
.Select(g => g.First())
...
```

Comment: because of the limitation of linq to ef that inner First query probably will throw exception.I remember I have tried something like this and I get UnsupportedException

Comment: @Selman22 the question is about linq to sql, so this would work just fine. But in case of EF, yes, you'd need to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`, which is a pretty simple fix.

Comment: In EF Core it throws exception even if you change it to `FirstOrDefault`. (The Linq expression [...] could not be translated...).