# LINQ query Distinct issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, linq, telerik

I need to perform this query:

> 1) List the processes
>
> 2) order them by name
>
> 3) eliminate duplicated names
>
> 4) instance a control with some data during the query

But i'm unable to use `Distinct` after ordering the process names (it does not take any effect), I never noticed this issue but its possibly that the `Distinct` statement only can be used as last statement of a query?

How I can fix/improve this query?

```
 From proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
 Where Not BlackListedProcesses.Contains(proc.ProcessName)
 Order By proc.ProcessName Ascending
 Select New RadListDataItem With
        {
            .Text = String.Format("{0}.exe", proc.ProcessName),
            .Image = ResizeImage(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(proc.MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap, Width:=16, Height:=16)
        }
```

> Update

I seen my fault too late, I'm trying to distinct the process objects and not their names because I didn't used the `Select` to select the process names then distinct them, but If I do that the subsequent `Select` statement receives a String and not a process...

How I can fix it?, I really will accomplish this only in 1 query...

```
 (From proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
 Where Not BlackListedProcesses.Contains(proc.ProcessName)
 Order By proc.ProcessName Ascending
 Select proc.ProcessName
 Distinct).
 Select(Function(p As Process)
            Return New RadListDataItem With
                        {
                            .Text = String.Format("{0}.exe", p.ProcessName),
                            .Image = ResizeImage(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap, Width:=16, Height:=16)
                        }
        End Function)
```

Comment: Could you share the code that you used `Distinct`?

Comment: Of course I can if neccessary but sorry I didn't understood what part of the code you mean, could you be more specific please?, I tried to use 'Distinct' after the 'Order By' and before, in the LINQ query because I need to eliminate duplicated process names before the 'Select' statement. This can be done in only 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DistinctBy()`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method from the 3rd party library by Jon Skeet; [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) :

```
.....
DistinctBy(Function(x) x.ProcessName)
.....
```

Or you can create a *class* that implement `IEqualityComparer(Of Process)` and pass the *class* instance to [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) method :

```
.....
Distinct(New ProcessComparer)
.....
```

Detailed explanation and other possible approach can be found in the following article by [Pranay Rana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314488/pranay-rana) :

[CodeProject : DistinctBy in Linq (Find Distinct object by Property)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535374/DistinctBy-in-Linq-Find-Distinct-object-by-Propert)

Comment: Thanks... its good to discover new libraries and also its a solution like any other and I really don't pretend to offend you but, installing a 3rd party library written by who knows and depending on that library in a project just to be rescued from 1 little and problematic query does not seems a good approach, I will not recommend that to anybody in the same situation like me. in the other hand, if I think it better maybe for cases where this issue need to be performed thousands of different times it could be great that library. thanks for your answer

Comment: Whether to pick 3rd party library is really up to you as it depends on many factors only you know it, but I found people recommending it for OPs in situation like you (eg. [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068277/linq-to-sql-order-by-with-distinct), and [what Jon Skeet him self did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645326/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-listof-t-using-linq)). Anyway, your comment proved I took the right step not stopping at the 1st suggestion, there are another 2 approaches available besides using MoreLINQ

Comment: Thankyou the soluttion suggested in the last answer of the first url solved my problem (grouping and then selecting the first item in the group), I know is not the more efficient way as LINQ appears to be a little slow (generally) but for my needs does not matter too much, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'll share the solution, this snippet is to update the datasource of a `RadListControl` (of Telerik control-suite for winForms) that contains the current processes (only the names):

```
Dim ProcessItems As IEnumerable(Of RadListDataItem) =
    (From proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    Where Not BlackListedProcesses.Contains(proc.ProcessName)
    Order By proc.ProcessName Ascending).
    GroupBy(Function(p As Process) p.ProcessName).
    Select(Function(p As IGrouping(Of String, Process))
               Return New RadListDataItem With
                          {
                            .Text = String.Format("{0}.exe", p.First.ProcessName),
                            .Image = ResizeImage(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.First.MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap, Width:=16, Height:=16)
                          }
           End Function)
```